# Custom animation in fragmentTransaction: enter animation "on top" of exit animation?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, fragment, android-animation

I want to make a fragment transaction with custom animations, where the enter animation slides in 100% and the exit animation slides out 25%, to achieve kind of a parallax effect. The problem is the entering view is below the exiting view (see gif), so at the end of the animation it is still on top and disappears abruptly. Is there any way to put the enter animation view on top of the exit one?

[image]

My code:

```
FragmentTransaction ft = ((AppCompatActivity) context).getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.enter_from_right, R.anim.exit_to_left_parallax, R.anim.enter_from_left_parallax, R.anim.exit_to_right);
final String tag = fragment.getClass().getSimpleName();
ft.replace(R.id.container, fragment, tag).addToBackStack(tag).commitAllowingStateLoss();
```